# Why can't I access my server via SSH or HTTP on my host machine, but i can on a virtual machine?

Tags: kubuntu

I have an Ubuntu 10.10 machine hosting a virtual Windows machine on virtualbox.

I have 3 servers I connect to using SSH with password authentication, on standard port (22)

For some unknown reason, I have one server that I cannot connect to Via SSH using putty/terminal or HTTP via Browser from my Host nix box, but my Virtual machine CAN connect via both.

Same machine, same network, one virtual with a bridged adapter, one physical network card connected to my network.

Really not sure where to start in troubleshooting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if the sshd_config file for the server that you can't connect to has something different in it from the other two servers that do work.  Also try and run "ssh -v" maybe that will tell you something.

Answer (score 1):

take a look to your `/etc/hosts`!

try to speak to your server via IP (not DNS)

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture of your network setup to make sure there are no other firewall devices intercepting traffic.  Use 'netstat -a' to verify that each machine has SSHd listening on it at port 22.   Make sure the service called "iptables" is temporarily stopped while you try to connect to each machine (you can sometimes use the app called Firestarter to do that or do it via the /etc/init.d scripts).  Make sure the service SShd is running.   Lots of things you can check but this sounds like the blockage should be easy to find.